# MediaRecorder start failed on setVideoSize()

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am developing on xperia z2 with lollipop.

My app records well wehn recording with the default size (1920*1080) or when i set it manually using setVideoSize(1920,1080) if I provide another resolution it fails with error code of -19.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

here is my code

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder()
{
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    // Step 4: Set output file
        outputUri = FileUtil.createOutputFile(Type.POST_QUESTION, Type.MEDIA_VIDEO); // custom methodthat returns Uri
    String path = new File(outputUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath();
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
    // set video resolution
     mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1600, 900); //fail
    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try
    {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and my logcat

```
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/MediaRecorder(5996): start failed: -19
07-04 19:01:34.656: D/AndroidRuntime(5996): Shutting down VM
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996): Process: com.dwaik.question, PID: 5996
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at com.dwaik.question.fragments.CaptureVideoFragment.startRecording(CaptureVideoFragment.java:243)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at com.dwaik.question.fragments.CaptureVideoFragment.onClick(CaptureVideoFragment.java:404)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
07-04 19:01:34.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: You cannot just make up video resolutions and expect them to work. Your video resolution needs to be one of the values returned by [`getSupportedVideoSizes()` on `Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29).

Comment: I have got the sizes, but there are no square resolution in them and i really need to record square video ie (640 , 640), do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGHT already set automatically the highest resolution in your phone (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html).

So, setting the resolution manually might be generating some inconsistency in the MediaPlayer parameters.

Also, your phone might not have the resolution you're trying to set (1600x900). You can get the available resolutions via the method getSupportedVideoSizes() in Camera.Parameters.

My suggestion: either use CamcorderProfile (which I prefer) or set it all manually. The frame rate limits might vary also depending on the phone.